# Authenticate on a website and Screen scraping with objective-c

Tags: objective-c, iphone, authentication, screen-scraping

I'm developing an iPhone application where I wish to authenticate (login form) on a site and retrieve some information by doing some screen scraping. Is there an API available to do this or documentation how I could do this?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) is a fantastic alternative to NSURLRequest, and the linked page has some great code examples to get you started on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

You may try [Gogybot](http://gogybot.com/) library for Monotouch. Its allow you to use very simple commands, like GoToUrl to open page, SetValue to enter text into text boxes and ClickSubmit to authenticate.

Answer (score -1):

See the docs for `NSURLRequest`

Comment: You are right. But I was hoping on more information. A tutorial or code example